# Handling multiple operations using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, datagridview, backgroundworker

I have a DataGridView on a winform. I am dynamically adding DatagridViewButtonColumn in the load method of form with button name as btnAction and text displayed on it as "Process".

So, every row in the grid would have this Process button in the last column.

On click event of this button, I am using a BackgroundWorker to call a method which does some calculations. Once the calculations are over, I need to update that clicked button's text as "Processed" in that row in the grid. Now, how do i handle this scenario?-->
The user clicks on multiple Process buttons and I need to trigger calculations for all the corresponding rows in the grid.Can it be handled using BackgroundWorker or I need to use threading here?

Please assist with code snippet if possible.

Comment: For context, this question was asked earlier where the response from the background worker was the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291842/updating-text-of-a-button-in-a-datagridview. Now I believe that the problem is running multiple background processes. @user74042 is that correct?

Comment: yes, thats right David.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the same BackgroundWorker cannot be called again while it is running. If you do that you will get an error:

> This BackgroundWorker is currently
>   busy and cannot run multiple tasks
>   concurrently.

This issue has been discussed here on StackOverflow: [This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588150/c-this-backgroundworker-is-currently-busy-and-cannot-run-multiple-tasks-concurre)

What you need to do is either create a new background worker for each button or queue your background worker requests. There is a queued background worker implementation [here](http://thevalerios.net/matt/2008/05/a-queued-backgroundworker/).

Whichever way you go you will need to be careful that the code you write is all threadsafe.

Comment: bust -> busy? - I think I prefer bust :)

Comment: And here is the example why we should copy code example on StackOverflow instead of just linking the resource...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario while using a BackgroundWorker process.

The following Codeproject article helped me a lot to get around it.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/BackgroundWorker_Threads.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.85).aspx

Will show you how to handle the backgroundworker.runworkercompleted event which will let you do something once the backgroundworker is done (whether by error or completion you will have to check).