# One backgroundworker object or multiple backgroundworker objects?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a .net windows app (a single form), there are many buttons like load data from db, next page, previous page, search etc. I want to use backgroundworker for all the buttons when they are clicked, so my UI is not frozen.

Question is that should I use 1 backgroundworker object throughout the form for all buttons or a separate backgroundworker per button?

Answer (score 0):

This post is useful, if you use only one you need to wrap all the db operations into one result. Otherwise you should use multiple backgroundworkers.

[Handling multiple operations using BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306503/handling-multiple-operations-using-backgroundworker)

Multiple would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task factory for this .No need to create your own background worker/workers, It is quicker.

```
 Task<bool> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>
 (() => /*Do you button operations */);
```

you can read more about tasks here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

please note that this requires .Net 4.5 , if you are targeting older Framewroks have a look a thread pool : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx